# Solving an ODE (does it have a name or standard method?)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $t\mapsto y(t)$ a function satisfying the following ODE:
$$y' = ay - \frac{1}{b_t+cy}+1,\quad y(1)=y_1\in \mathbb{R},$$
where $a$ and $c$ are known constants and $b_t$ is a known function.

Is there any standard method or way to find a solution of this ODE? Does it even have a name?

Comment: Multiply the equation by $c$ so that $$cy'=acy-\frac{c}{b_t+cy}+c$$ can be rewritten as $$(b_t+cy)'-(b_t)'=a(b_t+cy)-ab_t-\frac{c}{b_t+cy}+c.$$ Let $z=b_t+cy,$ hence $$z'-(b_t)'=az-ab_t-\frac{c}{z}+c.$$ This can be rewritten as $$z'+\frac{c}{z}-az=(b_t)'-ab_t+c.$$ Perhaps this may help you.

Comment: Thanks! But how is the last equation better? How do I solve that one?

Comment: I think the last equation is closer to being separable.

Comment: I don't manage to solve it either, I'm stuck there still :(

Comment: The equation is an Abel equation of the second kind. For certain $b_t$ you can find solutions, for example, if $b_t’-ab_t+c=0$ the equation is solvable using an integrating factor. The general solution is known, and I’ve posted it before, but I’m not entirely convinced by it.